# Warning users on required fields C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm working on a frameworkish structure for my projects using entity framework
I'm currently using Database first but may change it to CodeFirst if required. So my question here is I want to add some logic to my CRUDS how do I do this in a generic way? are there any best practices? I've search the web but couldn't find anything on this.

Here's an example to show what I need:
assume I have a **CLIENTS** table with the following fields

- C_ROWID (int) (primary key) (AI)(NOT_NULL)
- C_CLIENT_ID  (int)
- C_IS_EMPLOYEED (bool)
- C_JOB_TITLE (string)

so the scenario is this: when making a new registration 
the user needs to enter the C_CLIENT_ID

and if the C_IS_EMPLOYED is true
then I would also like to force the user to enter the Job title of the client as well.

so in the above scenario, if C_IS_EMPLOYEE is true and the user leaves the client id and job title fields blank, I would like to display a warning for the user that these fields are required and not save the information.

so what are your suggestions?

Comment: As a quick answer, you will probably need some kind of dependency tree.

Comment: What front-end will you use? If you use APS.NET MVC, you can quite easily adorn your models with validation rules and use standard functionality to validate and show validation errors to the user.

Comment: Off-topic: if `Client_Id` is supposed to be a primary key (it looks like it), do NOT tell your user to provide it for a new entry. Have your database generate it. Why on earth would I, as a user, be expected to provide a number for a new entry, especially since I don't know which numbers are in use already?

Comment: Alright I have updated, the example. so now I have a C_ROWID as a primary key.  and I'm not using asp. I'm using C# winforms

Comment: @oerkelens I meant on an ai table,I have updated my question the client id field was for the id card number of the user.

Answer (score 0):

What I do in order to enforce a selection for required foreign key:

```
public class SomeDataEntity
{
    public int PrimaryKey { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int? ForeignKey { get; set; }
}
```

By using `Nullable`, the default value will be `null`
 when nothing was selected and the `Required` attribute will be recognized both by EF and by typical validation techniques.

The other requirement is more complicated.

On the database level, you could introduce a [`CHECK` constraint](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp). Make sure to select a boolean comparison and string comparison that works for your database. For some databases, `C_JOB_TITLE` could still be empty without being `NULL`.

```
CONSTRAINT CHK_JobTitle CHECK (C_IS_EMPLOYEED = 0 OR C_JOB_TITLE IS NOT NULL)
```

On application level, you could develop some custom validation attribute. The following is just a pretty unrefined rough sketch of what's possible:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = true)]
sealed class RequiredIfAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    readonly string boolPropertyName;

    public RequiredIfAttribute(string boolPropertyName)
    {
        this.boolPropertyName = boolPropertyName;

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public string BoolPropertyName
    {
        get { return boolPropertyName; }
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var prop = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(BoolPropertyName);
        if (prop == null)
        {
            throw new ValidationException("Property not found: " + BoolPropertyName);
        }
        var condition = prop.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance) as bool?;
        if (condition == true && string.IsNullOrEmpty(value as string))
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Required: " + validationContext.MemberName);
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Usage

```
public class SomeDataEntity
{
    public int PrimaryKey { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int? ForeignKey { get; set; }

    public bool C_IS_EMPLOYEED { get; set; }

    [RequiredIf("C_IS_EMPLOYEED")]
    public string C_JOB_TITLE { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: *then I would also like to force the user to enter the Job title*

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks, my bad focusing on one question, I'll edit :D